# eth0 no longer claiming address on Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, ethernet

I am running Debian 8.6 and out of the blue it is failing to get an eth0 address.

```
/etc/network/interfaces looks like this:

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback 

auto eth0 inet dhcp
```

I didn't explicitly upgrade anything on the OS and other computers are connecting to the network.

Can anyone provide any insight of what might have gone wrong and how?

Comment: Read: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/

Answer (score 4):

The default interface names were renamed by systemd. If you want the old behavior, pass the `net.ifnames=0` parameter to kernel. (in grub.cfg or `/etc/default/grub`)

Comment: I'd suggest including BOTH the following parameters:  net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0

Comment: Debian Jessie use by default the old name for network-devices. `eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 00:26:2d:ad:29:57  
,wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 20:7c:8f:01:a1:61` It must be another fault.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone provide any insight of what might have gone wrong and how?

A quick answer can be found on [Archlinux-wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration#Device_names):

> For computers with multiple NICs, it is important to have fixed device names. Many configuration problems are caused by interface name changing.
>   udev is responsible for which device gets which name. Systemd v197 introduced Predictable Network Interface Names, which automatically assigns static names to network devices. Interfaces are now prefixed with en (wired/Ethernet), wl (wireless/WLAN), or ww (WWAN) followed by an automatically generated identifier, creating an entry such as `enp0s25`. This behavior may be disabled by adding `net.ifnames=0` to the kernel parameters.

To get the previous interface names you can :

1) Edit your `/etc/default/grub`  change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` to :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0"
```

If the `biosdevname` is installed you need to add :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"
```

Update grub:

```
update-grub
```

or

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

and reboot

2)Also you can create a new `udev-rule` :

Edit the `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` then change the name of your interface to `eth0`

3) If the [`biosdevname`](http://linux.dell.com/biosdevname/biosdevname-0.7.2/) package is installed on your system 
remove it then update initramfs

```
apt-get purge biosdevname
update-initramfs -u
```

Remove `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` then edit your `/etc/network/interfaces` (in your case it's Ok) , Reboot your system